# why increment variable changing the value of the array when they have different names

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, boolean

Can someone please help me. I am struggling to find in my code why the last value in column  B always gets incremented by one. I have written some code since its an assignment due today. I also cant figure out why the last value in column B is not equal to 196 because in the reset function it sets all the values in the array  to 196 . Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream> //includes cin cout

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; //setting up the    environment

const int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 3;
const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 3;

void printAllSeats(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
void reset(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
void askForUsersSeat(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], int &SeatCountNumber, bool &anyFreeSeats);
bool isFull(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
bool isEmpty(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);

int main() { //main starts
    int maxSeats;

    int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    int SeatCountNumber = 0;
    bool anyFreeSeats;

    reset(seats);

    anyFreeSeats = true;

    SeatCountNumber = 0;
    while (anyFreeSeats) {

        printAllSeats(seats);

        askForUsersSeat(seats, SeatCountNumber, anyFreeSeats);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

} //main ends

void printAllSeats(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "              - = Available      R =   Reserved\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {
        cout << setw(15) << i << " ";

        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cout << "  " << static_cast<char>(j + 65) << "   ";
            } else {
                cout << "  " << static_cast<char>(seats[i][j]) << "   ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void reset(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]) {

    //set all values in array to  196

    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++) {
            seats[i][j] = 196;
        }
    }
}

void askForUsersSeat(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], int &SeatCountNumber, bool &anyFreeSeats) {
    int seatChoiceNumber;
    char seatChoiceLetter;
    int letter;

    int maxSeats = NUMBER_OF_ROWS * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;

    cout << "Seat (Row, Column):    ";
    cin >> seatChoiceNumber >> seatChoiceLetter;
    letter = static_cast<int>(toupper(seatChoiceLetter));

    if (((letter >= 65) && (letter < (65 + NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS))) && ((seatChoiceNumber > 0) && (seatChoiceNumber <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS))) {
        if (seats[(seatChoiceNumber)][(letter - 65)] == 82) {

        } else {
            seats[(seatChoiceNumber)][(letter - 65)] = 82;

            SeatCountNumber++; //this changes last value in column  B for some reason

            if (SeatCountNumber < maxSeats) {
                anyFreeSeats = true;
            }

            else if (SeatCountNumber > maxSeats) {
                printAllSeats(seats);
                anyFreeSeats = false;
            }
        }

    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: `i <=  NUMBER_OF_ROWS` - use `<` not `<=` - with current version you are out of range correct this error and return to the question if still does not work...

Comment: no but i really dont know how to use code blocks im sorry i just needed some help im gonna try to edit it so its more read able

Comment: @ PiotrNycz it worked in getting rid of that funny character ! Thank you

Comment: @PiotrNycz the matrix that print out is a 3x2 when the array is a 3x3. what should I change i <= NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS use < not <=  or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have fixed all my problems thank you @PiotrNycz once again

Answer (score 0):

I kind of cleaned up the code a bit. It seems you found your answer in the comments, so I just did some indentation. Try and eliminate whitespaces in your code (mind you, the one I am putting here is not perfect either, but you get the point). Clean and easy to read code doesn't only make it better for you, but as you get higher up in the industry and other people begin reading and working on your code, having clean and easy to read code really helps :)

```
#include <iostream> //includes cin cout
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; //setting up the    environment

const int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 3;
const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 3;

void printAllSeats(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
void reset(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
void askForUsersSeat(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], int &SeatCountNumber, bool &anyFreeSeats);
bool isFull(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);
bool isEmpty(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]);

int main() 
{ 
    int maxSeats;
    int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    int SeatCountNumber = 0;
    bool anyFreeSeats;

    reset(seats);

    anyFreeSeats = true;
    SeatCountNumber = 0;

    while (anyFreeSeats)
    {
        printAllSeats(seats);
        askForUsersSeat(seats, SeatCountNumber, anyFreeSeats);
    }

    system("pause");
        return 0;
} //main ends

void printAllSeats(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "              - = Available      R =   Reserved\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(15) << i << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                cout << "  " << static_cast<char>(j + 65) << "   ";
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "  " << static_cast<char>(seats[i][j]) << "   ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void reset(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{
    //set all values in array to  196
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            seats[i][j] = 196;
        }
    }
}

void askForUsersSeat(int seats[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], int &SeatCountNumber, bool &anyFreeSeats)
{
    int seatChoiceNumber;
    char seatChoiceLetter;
    int letter;
    int maxSeats = NUMBER_OF_ROWS * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;

    cout << "Seat (Row, Column):    ";
    cin >> seatChoiceNumber >> seatChoiceLetter;
    letter = static_cast<int>(toupper(seatChoiceLetter));

    if (((letter >= 65) && (letter < (65 + NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS))) && ((seatChoiceNumber > 0) && (seatChoiceNumber <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS)))
    {
        if (seats[(seatChoiceNumber)][(letter - 65)] == 82)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            seats[(seatChoiceNumber)][(letter - 65)] = 82;
            SeatCountNumber++; //this changes last value in column  B for some reason

            if (SeatCountNumber < maxSeats)
            {
                anyFreeSeats = true;
            }
            else if (SeatCountNumber > maxSeats)
            {
                printAllSeats(seats);
                anyFreeSeats = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Note: Some more whitespaces could even come out but I generally like to have spaces after certain statements (personal preference).

Comment: as other have said you need < not <= on your for conditions